# I need a code to incremeny a column in my table when condition is satisfied

Tags: php, sql

The below one is the code i'm using for incrementing,it shows no error but the "like" column is not incrementing.

```
   <?php
      $id=$_GET['id'];
     echo $id;
     $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=as1';
     $user = 'root';
     $password = '';

    try{
                // Connect and create the PDO object
                $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
         catch(PDOException $e){
                                    echo 'Database connection failed - ';
                                    echo $e->getMessage();
                                    exit;
                                }
        $sql="UPDATE photo SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE imagename=:id";
        $q=$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        header("Location:upload.php");
}
```

Comment: $sql="UPDATE photo SET \`likes\` = \`likes\`+1 WHERE imagename=':id'";

Comment: UPDATE photo SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE imagename=':id'

Comment: @farkie Hey its not working its shows a fatal error

Comment: @ratneshdwivedi your code also not incrementing any value

Comment: it seems your issue is not the SQL... post the rest of the code

Comment: @prakashfire Are you using PDO? You do not need the quotes around your `:id` entry. If you are getting an error please update here so we know what error you are getting.

Comment: @MikeHancock Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp32\www\like.php on line 19
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp32\www\like.php on line 19

Comment: @prakashfire Change this: `$q->execute(array($id));` to `$q->execute(array(':id'=>$id));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE photo SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE imagename=:id";
$q=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
```

`++` known from programming languages does not work with normal SQL syntax.

Comment: your code  also not showing any error,but its not incrementing

Comment: if i didnt use quotes then its a Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp32\www\like.php on line 19 PDOException:

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE photo SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE imagename=':id'";
```